# Session gets lost once user is redirected, works fine on localhost

Tags: php, session

I have a login script that works fine on localhost but does not work when uploaded to a web server.

The program checks if username and password are correct and if yes, a session is set.
However, when the user is redirected to the same page again the session is lost - despite the credentials being correct the user does not get logged in. Here is the code:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  include ('dbconn.php');

  $username = $_POST['usernameinput'];
  $password = $_POST['passwordinput'];

  $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."';");
  $hashedpwd = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT password FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."';");

  if (!$hashedpwd) {
    printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
    exit();
  }

  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($hashedpwd);

  if (mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0 && password_verify($password, $row[0]) == 1) {
    
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    
  } else {
      header("Location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?status=login_fail");
  }
 ?>
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? I think it may have to do with cookies somehow not being saved but I am too much of a beginner with php to know. I would be forever grateful for some help.

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` sets the session but ur not calling the session try `$_session['username'];`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks dean,

The answer was to call the session with $_SESSION['username'];
at the top of every file I wanted to keep the session for.

For some reason I did not have to do that on localhost but I guess the session is not kept on a domain unless specified.